# Get unique strings from group of strings using JQ

Tags: json, stream, unique, jq

I have strings extracted from jq , from which I just want to get unique values.

```
"a-b-c-v001"
"a-b-c-v002"
"a-b-c-v001"
"a-b-c-v003"
"a-b-c-v002"
```

I just need 3 results, unique

```
"a-b-c-v001"
"a-b-c-v002"
"a-b-c-v003"
```

I have tried unique & sort did not work - https://jqplay.org/s/xjND6Iv60T

Comment: show how did you extract those values? show your `jq` expression

Comment: Generally, jq works on JSON. This is what you are looking for -> https://jqplay.org/s/Sk7_j2zho5

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make sure your jq expression produces an array. For example, if your jq expression (the one producing a stream of strings) is E, then you could modify it to:

```
[E] | unique | .[]
```

or just:

```
[E] | unique[]
```

#### Avoiding a sort

`unique` involves a sort, which can easily be avoided if E as above produces a stream of strings:

```
INDEX(E;.)[]
```

So, in answer to a Q in a comment, a sort-free way to get the count of distinct strings would be:

```
def count(s): reduce s as $x (0;.+1);
count( INDEX(E;.)[] )
```

Comment: Is there a way to get count/length of the unique elements too?

Answer (score 1):

**jq** processor itself has **`unique`** function:

Let's assume the following `input.json`:

```
[
  "a-b-c-v001",
  "a-b-c-v002",
  "a-b-c-v001",
  "a-b-c-v003",
  "a-b-c-v002"
]
```

---

```
jq 'unique' input.json
```

The output:

```
[
  "a-b-c-v001",
  "a-b-c-v002",
  "a-b-c-v003"
]
```